# можно ли отрисовывать графики в многопоточном режиме

Tags: python, matplotlib

```py
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.switch_backend('Qt5Agg')


class test:
    @staticmethod
    def plot(a, b, c):
        print(a)
        fig, ax = plt.subplots(num=f'{a}{b}{c}')
        ax.plot([a, a], [c, c])

        return fig


if __name__ == '__main__':
    t = test()
    args = [(i, i + 1, i + 2) for i in range(4)]
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=2) as executor:
        figs = list(executor.map(lambda i: t.plot(*i), args))
    print(figs)
```

Возможно ли отрисовывать графики в асинхронном режиме используя потоки? Запуск скрипта заканчивается ошибкой `Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)`, но даже если указать `max_workers=1`, код в 20-30% случаях заканчивается этой же ошибкой.

python 3.7

windows 10

matplotlib 3.1.3

Comment: Зачем вам это? В большинстве систем `GUI` однопоточный и он должен отрисовываться в главном потоке программы. Готовьте данные многопоточно, получайте их в основном потоке - и там уже рисуйте, такая должна быть схема по идее.

Comment: @CrazyElf, может он графики не отображать хочет, а сохранять куда-нибудь в файл...

Comment: @maestro Мысль интересная. Ну тогда по идее проблема должна решаться заменой потоков на процессы. Хотя нужно проверять.

Comment: Если задача сохранить в файл, то имеет смысл вообще отвязаться от `gui` бэкенда. Это должно упростить задачу распараллеливания.

Comment: @CrazyElf у меня программка может отображать выбранный график по данным, и есть кнопка "отчет" если нажать на нее должны сформироваться  и сохраниться все доступные графики по этим данным, а после я их вставляю в word документ

Comment: @user207200 я ответил выше на комментарий, возможно ли переключать бэкенд во время формирования отчета, функция формирования отчета в дальнейшем будет выведена в отдельный процесс, то есть из основного процесса будет запускаться еще один где будет происходить отрисовка и сохранение. и есть ли рабочий бэк для асинхронной работы ?

Answer (score 0):

Нужно использовать бэкенд Agg для отрисовки графиков в асинхронном режиме, а перед показом переключиться на бэкенд TkAgg, он поддерживает графики отрисованные в Agg